# CubeJS pre-aggregations error: relation "dev_pre_aggregations.product_base" does not exist

Tags: javascript, postgresql, analytics, cube

I'm using CubeJS pre-aggregation of type `original_sql` like this in a cube `Product`:

```js
  pre_aggregations: {
    base: {
      type: `original_sql`,
      external: false,
    },

    main: {
      dimensions: [
          Product.product_sid,
          Product.amount,
      ],
      use_original_sql_pre_aggregations: true,
      refresh_key: {
        every: `1 day`,
      },
    },
  },
```

But when I run the query from CubeJS playground, it gives me error `relation "dev_pre_aggregations.product_base" does not exist`.

I tried checking CubeJS [docs](https://cube.dev/docs/product/caching) and other resources but I'm not able to find any fix.

The datastore used for pre-aggregations is PostgreSQL.

EDIT 1:
When I checked the database, the schema `dev_pre_aggregations` and table `product_base` is created but the table name has some random suffix like `product_base_ery3312`. And I can see those tables are being created on every few minutes even if the refresh key was set to `1 day`.

Comment: "dev_pre_aggregations.product_base" would be a single object name that just happened to contain a dot (.). However looks like you want too objects (something like `schema_name.table_name`). If you want double quotes on your object names then you need `"dev_pre_aggregations"."product_base". However, double quotes are not needed as no upper case nor *special characters* are in the names.

Comment: @Belayer The double quotes are just in the error message but in reality it's `schema_name.table_name`. `dev_pre_aggregations` is a schema and `product_base` is a table.